# How to make a private Chromecast app, not meant to be published?

Tags: android, chromecast

I have downloaded the CastVideos-android and made changes to it so it fits my needs... But probably only my needs! It will not be usable by anyone else, this is for my intranet configuration only...

It works fine using the `app_id` provided in the `refplayer`, but changing it to my own `app_id`, the Chromecast icon doesn't show up. This has to do with the app not being correctly registered at the Dev Console, but...

Since this is an app that is never meant to be published, what do I do to make the icon appear and my app to work for me, myself and I alone?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can login to your Cast Developer Console and add the serial numbers of the Chromecast devices that you own. Doing that allows those cast devices to recognize your unpublished app; for a small number of Cast devices, this is a pretty manageable solution.

Comment: Yes, but I suppose you have already gone there to create your own app id for a Styled receiver? Assuming so, log back in there and make sure you see your app id and then add devices. Reading off the chromecast serial numbers may be a bit tricky so take a picture and enlarge,  use TV screen or voice to double check it and then wait 15 minutes, reboot your chromecast and you should be good to go.

Comment: You seem to be the Godfather of Chromecast for Android! You answer every question I've seen, and correctly. Thank You! I indeed wen't there, paid the small fee, added a styles receiver (the second time), added my Chromecast ID and forgot to reboot my Chromecast ;) Didn't work but...Once rebooted, it works like i charm! THANK YOU!